# Angular Expression is shared while sharing in addthis not expression value

Tags: angularjs, html, sharethis

Here is my angular controller:
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
  myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$sce',     function      ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.greeting = 'my test goes here';
  $scope.url = "http://google.com";
  var shartthis = "<div addthis-toolbox class='addthis_toolbox   addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style' addthis:url='{{url}}' ng-attr-addthis:title='{{greeting}}'><a class='addthis_button_facebook'></a><a class='addthis_button_twitter'></a> <a class='addthis_button_google_plusone_share'></a><a class='addthis_button_compact'></a><a class='addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style'></a> <script type='text/javascript'>var addthis_config = {'data_track_clickback': false, 'data_track_addressbar': false ,};</script></div>";
  $scope.shartthishtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(shartthis);
   } ]);
```

and this is my HTML page :

```
<body ng-controller="GreetingController" ng-model="greeting">
<div ng-model="greeting">
{{greeting}}
</div>
<div ng-bind-html="shartthishtml"></div>
```

Sharethis button is displaying but when share something it display Angular syntax not its value.

[image: Here is the example what it is shared]

no any console error

Comment: Do you see any error message in developer console ?

Comment: <div ng-model="greeting">
This might be the error.. please remove ng-model from the <div>

Answer (score 1):

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', '$sce',     function      ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.greeting = 'my test goes here';
  $scope.url = "http://google.com";
  var shartthis = "<div addthis-toolbox class='addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style' addthis:url='{{url}}' ng-attr-addthis:title='{{greeting}}'><a class='addthis_button_facebook'></a><a class='addthis_button_twitter'></a> <a class='addthis_button_google_plusone_share'></a><a class='addthis_button_compact'></a><a class='addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style'></a> <script type='text/javascript'>var addthis_config = {'data_track_clickback': false, 'data_track_addressbar': false ,};</script></div>";
  $scope.shartthishtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(shartthis);
   } ]);





 <body ng-controller="GreetingController">
<div>{{greeting}}</div>
<div ng-bind-html="shartthishtml"></div>
</body>
```